# How do I mount devices so that they are accessible by regular user?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, encryption, mount, unrooting

I am using luksmanager to mount my file based luks container. It is mapped to `/dev/mapper/luksfile`. It works, and it works great except that only root can see the files.

I successfully used this on Kitkat meaning that regular user was able to access mounted folders. However I upgraded to Lollipop recently and old way of mounting the folders does not work anymore. So only root can access the mounted folders. for everyone else the folder icon is just a file type which is broken.

I want to be able  to mount the `/dev/mapper/luksfile` so that it can be accessed by reguular users on Lollipop. I also used `mount  -o bind` to distribute some of the folders in the container, those naturally do not work too.

I tried:

```
mount -t ext4 -o rw /dev/mapper/luksfile /storage/.sdcard/mnt
```

without success

---

I am using CM12 5.1

Comment: Try disabling the SE Linux Enforcement in the boot image of the device, and I guess after that, you'll be able to do it as you did in KitKat.